# Looking for a TV show about young people at a boarding school?

Tags: story-identification, tv, childrens-novel

My sister and I both remember a live-action television show that aired in the US sometime around 2003.  It consisted of 3-5 preteens or teenagers at a boarding school.  My sister thinks they were in Britain, but I don't agree.

What we do agree on was a supernatural aspect.  This was more science-based than magic.  I don't remember ghosts or vampires, but maybe robots or shrinking people- things like that.

As for the cast, we're both pretty sure there was a male science teacher who was a good guy.  I remember a female teacher being an antagonist, but my sister thinks she was more of an annoyance than a bad guy (she compared her to Filch in Harry Potter).  We agree that there was definitely a redheaded girl, and possibly a black girl (but she might have been a later addition).  There were two or three boys.  One was very smart and kind of a geek.  The other(s)- one might have been kind of slow on the uptake? The other was rich, I think.  They might have been the same person.

Its maddening that we both remember watching this show, but neither of us knows what its called.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've tagged this "childrens-novel" because I wanted to make it clear that it was not aimed at adults, and there was no similar tag for other media.  Should we think about fixing that?

Comment: "Novel" isn't right, but it's hard to say whether it not "children's" fits.  If it is _Strange Days at Blake Holsey High_, it seems aimed more towards the pre-teen age group.

Comment: Sounds a bit like 'Hex' to me: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0423668/

Comment: @Izkata Huh? I thought "children" = "under 40".

Comment: @user14111 As a generic term, child/children usually means before puberty.  Pre-teen (around when puberty starts) and teenager are the next age groups up

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds to me like it could be the TV show called [Strange Days at Blake Holsey High](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_at_Blake_Holsey_High) (called Black Hole High in some markets).

- Aired 2002-2006
- Revolved around the 5-student Science Club at a boarding school
- Said club had a male science teacher
- The Principal was female, aided the 'bad guys' reluctantly
- The main pupil was a red-headed girl
- Plots involved the effects of the school being ontop of a wormhole - the main female shrunk in one episode, in another there was a clone created (who became a recurring character)
- Story arcs involved a wormhole and time travel effects/consequences, a floating ball, and a nearby laboratory that exploded prior to the series main time period called 'Pearadyne Labs'.

I hope this might prod some memories if this is the correct identification.

Comment: Dangit, you beat me to it!  I'm actually watching the series right now  =)

Comment: The OP's "two or three" boys could even fit in - Vaughn, the third boy, is a reluctant Science Club member who was pretty much ordered to join

Answer (score 1):

I could have been [*House of Anubis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Anubis) which was about kids in boarding school in the UK yes and it was a little paranormal too.

Comment: Can you provide any details? They already have an accepted answer. Providing a matching answer is still useful, for later querents, but you have to explain why it matches so that it can hit the right keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like *H2O - Just add water* which aired in Australia 
There are only around three guys in that show and one is rich and another is kind of nerdy. Also there is an evil sort of girl that comes in the show named sharlet who has red hair.

The plot of the show is that there are three girls who turn into mermaids whenever they are exposed to water.

Comment: The only thing H2O has in common with the show described in the question is that they're both about teenagers and involve magic.

Answer (score -1):

A new one called Make it pop! about three girls at a boarding school wanting to become famous.
Here's a link to some episodes http://watchseries.lt/serie/make_it_pop

Comment: Given they said 2003, it's probably not new. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's house of anubis 
Its a tv series about some kids in a boarding school in england 
check it out

Comment: What makes you think this? Can you add any details to your answer about how this show fits the OP's criteria?

Answer (score -2):

The show you are referring to sounds like zoey 101, a show that aired on Teen Nick and it's set in a boarding school called PCA in california

Comment: Can you address any of the other details in the question?